# pyqt: show() for labels shows up in different window?

Tags: python, pyqt, show

Here is part of my code that is in my function which is called when a user presses a button on the GUI.

```
self.titlelbl.clear()  #clear labels
self.genrelbl.clear()
self.ratinglbl.clear()
#........ Other code ....

self.titlelbl = QLabel(self.movie['title'])  #Labels, defined earlier 
self.genrelbl = QLabel(self.movie['genre'])
self.ratinglbl = QLabel(self.movie['rating'])

self.titlelbl.show()     #Show labels
self.genrelbl.show()
self.ratinglbl.show()
```

The issue I'm having is that when the new labels show up again **the information on the labels is correct but the GUI opens up a new window for each label** instead of just displaying them in the main GUI window, like it displays when you first open the program. 
What is causing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `parent` for each label.

```
...
self.titleLbl = QLabel(self, self.movie['title'])
...
```

then add the labels to the `layout` of the mainWindow.